# Как убрать Array ( [0] => )

Tags: регулярные-выражения, curl, php

Можете закидывать меня помидорами, но мне уже плохо :D

Имеется код:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init ();
curl_setopt ($ch , CURLOPT_URL , "http://ru.oriflame.com/products/product-detail.jhtml?prodCode=22860");
curl_setopt ($ch , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , 1 ); 
$content = curl_exec($ch);
preg_match('/\<p class=\"description\">.*\<\/p\>/Uis', $content, $test);
print_r ($test);
curl_close($ch);                  
?>
```

При этом на странице отображается вот так:

> Array ( [0] => Усовершенствованная
> формула эффективно удаляет макияж,
> мягко воздействуя на чувствительную
> область вокруг глаз. Натуральные
> ингредиенты смягчают и освежают кожу.
> Нанеси средство на ватный диск и
> протри кожу. 0.23  мл.
>
> )

Как убрать "Как убрать Array ( [0] => )"?

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Если echo $test я пробовал, то [0] прибавить я не догадался) Еще раз огромное спасибо)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В результате работы функции `preg_match()` переменная `$test` становится массивом. Собственно поэтому и используется для ее вывода функция `print_r()`. Скорее всего, если оформите вывод как `echo $test[0];` - Вам станет лучше.